# error with the declaration of enum

Tags: c

I have a very simple c code:

```
         #include<stdio.h>
        int main()
        {
          enum boolean{true,false};
          boolean bl=false;
          if(bl==false)
             printf("This is the false value of boool\n");
         boolean bl1=true;
          if(bl1==true)
           {
            printf("This is the true value of boool\n");
           }
    return 0;
   }
```

i was just trying to use **enum** type variable .but it is giving following error:

```
tryit4.c:5: error: ‘boolean’ undeclared (first use in this function)
tryit4.c:5: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
tryit4.c:5: error: for each function it appears in.)
tryit4.c:5: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘bl’
tryit4.c:6: error: ‘bl’ undeclared (first use in this function)
tryit4.c:8: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘bl1’
tryit4.c:9: error: ‘bl1’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I don't see any reason for it.  Can you please explain what could be the reason for it?

Comment: some gyz probably have too much free time and nothing better to do than get angry on the Internet.

Comment: @mawia: Click on your username, choose "activity" then go through all the questions you have asked and choose a best answer from each.

Comment: It looks as if you can not **compile** it right. True and false are the keywords of C.
You will get the error "cannot convert `‘bool’` to `‘main(int, const char**)::boolean’`" in initialization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you declare `enum boolean { true, false }`, you declare a type called `enum boolean`. That the name you'll have to use after that declaration: `enum boolean`, not just `boolean`.

If you want a shorter name (like just `boolean`), you'll have to define it as an alias for the original full name

```
typedef enum boolean boolean;
```

If you wish, you can declare both the `enum boolean` type and the `boolean` alias on one declaration

```
typedef enum boolean { true, false } boolean;
```

Answer (score 11):

In C, there are two (actually more, but i keep it at this) kind of namespaces: Ordinary identifiers, and tag identifiers. A struct, union or enum declaration introduces a tag identifier:

```
enum boolean { true, false };
enum boolean bl = false;
```

The namespace from which the identifier is chosen is specified by the syntax around. Here, it is prepended by a `enum`. If you want to introduce an ordinary identifier, put it inside a typedef declaration

```
typedef enum { true, false } boolean;
boolean bl = false;
```

Ordinary identifiers don't need special syntax. You may declare a tag and ordinary one too, if you like.

Comment: what would you say about the declaration style given for enum on page 39 in kernigham and richie.
ex enum boolean {yes,no}.

Comment: @mawia: in `enum boolean {yes, no}` the name `boolean` is being used as a tag identifier. In `typedef enum {true, false} boolean`, the name `boolean` is being used as an ordinary identifier. It's a tag identifier if it comes right after `enum` or `struct` or `union`.

Answer (score 7):

You have to declare the variables to be of type enum boolean, not just boolean. Use typedef, if you find writing enum boolean b1 = foo(); cumbersome.

Answer (score 7):

It would really be a good idea to define your enum like this:

```
typedef enum {
  False,
  True,
} boolean;
```

A couple of reasons:

- `true` and `false` (lowercase) are likely reserved words
- false being 1 and true being 0 can cause you logic problems later

Comment: +1 for catching the problem with defining them in the other order.

Answer (score 3):

You declare the enum, but not the type.  What you want is

```
typedef enum{false, true} boolean;  // false = 0 is expected by most programmers
```

There are still multiple problems with this:
* `true` and `false` are reserved words in many C compilers
* explicitly using true and false goes against the general practice of Boolean expressions in C, where zero means false and anything non-zero means true.  For example:

```
int found = (a == b);
```

---

Edit:  This works with gcc 4.1.2:

```
[wally@zf ~]$ ./a.out
This is the false value of boool
This is the true value of boool
[wally@zf ~]$ cat t2.c
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        typedef enum {true,false} boolean;
        boolean bl=false;
        if(bl==false)
                printf("This is the false value of boool\n");
        boolean bl1=true;
        if(bl1==true)
        {
                printf("This is the true value of boool\n");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first issue can be worked-around by adding underscore prefix, or something.

Comment: thanks for reply,
hey unfortunately problem persisted even after typedefining the enum.

Comment: yeah prog compiled perfectly on typedef like typedef enum{false,true} boolean;
but what would you say to the style given on page 39 of kernigham and richie of declaring an enum!

Answer (score 1):

Like previous answers demonstrate, use typedef:

```
typedef enum { true, false } boolean;
```

Comment: If there are previous answers, to what benefit is there adding a duplicate answer?

Answer (score 0):

From **[FAQ](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1047588051&id=1043284376)** - A list of features that C++ supports which C does not includes:

`bool keyword`

That FAQ is a little inaccurate, and is better stated as "a list of features that C++ supports which C89 does not include"

Add `#include <stdbool.h>` to your code and it will compile as C99 on a compiler that attempts to implement C99 (such as gcc).