# enum included with header | Error not declared

Tags: c++, enums, declaration

Maumau_game.h:

```
#ifndef MAUMAU_GAME_H_
#define MAUMAU_GAME_H_

#include <more_includes>
#include "Player.h"

enum game_status {
    STATUS_NONE = 0,
    STATUS_DRAW_2 = 1,
};

class Maumaugame_holder {
methods();
};

#endif /* MAUMAU_GAME_H_ */
```

Player.h:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H_
#define PLAYER_H_

#include <vector>
#include "Maumau_game.h"
#include "Card.h"

class Player {
more_methods();

public:
    void do_turn(game_status g_status, const Card upper_dropped_card,
            Deck& talon); //Error: >>game_status<< not declared 


};

#endif /* PLAYER_H_ */
```

I have no clue why the enum game_status is not declared. I have included the header properly and it is in the scope, isn't it? I cant declare the enum in the "Player.h" eiter. I would have declared it twice. Can you help me please? Do you have any suggestions?

(I am not allowed to use C++11)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a circular include. Do not include player.h inside  Maumau_game.h

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909825/error-with-the-declaration-of-enum . At any rate I think the answers in this question will fix your problem.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but those initializers in the `enum` are redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you include `Player.h` that includes `Maumau_game.h` that tries to include `Player.h` and at that last include the definition is not present.

One way to fix this is to forward declare the enum in `Player.h` (by adding a line `enum game_status`) , remove the include for `Maumau_game.h` (from `Player.h`) and change the argument from `game_status g_status` to `const game_status& g_status` in `do_turn` function.

Comment: "and so on until the compiler will stops reasoning" - not really, they're each included at most twice because of the include guards. The problem is the order in which the types are declared.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore whell yes , i just wanted to make it sound more dramathic :)

Comment: I moved the enum "game_status" to Player.h and removed the circular include. It worked. But is there any way to declare the enum in "Maumaugame_holder.h" and use it in the Player Class?

Comment: @L1ttleb1rd not directly, i mean that you have to forward declare the enum in the header (this tell the compiler about it's existence) and after that use it in the cpp where you can include the acutal definition of the enum. To forward declare you can write `enum game_status;` in the `Maumaugame_holder.h` and define it in the `player.h` After that you can use it in the Maumaugame_holder.cpp where you can safely include `Player.h`. Search on google for `c++ forward declaration` for further information bout this.

Comment: IIRC forward-declaring enum's isn't standard. @L1ttleb1rd the correct fix would be to remove superfluous includes, not moving definitions around until it compiles. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/72599/673730

Comment: @Luchian Grigore forwarding enum declaration is indeed strange, but you can use reference in any declaration so it's ok. The best way is to move the enum declaration into a separate header and include that everywhere.

Comment: Not strange, but illegal (but there are compiler extensions that allow it). It shouldn't be done.

Comment: I am only allowed to use c++98, so forward declaration of the enum is not an option. @LuchianGrigore What is your opinion about outsourcing the enum (or all enums) in a single header file and include this in both code files?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is a circular include, remove the

```
#include "Player.h"
```

from `Maumau_game.h` and it should work. Only include what you need and forward-declare anything you can.